# Validar la carga de un CardView en RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, recyclerview

Tengo una validación en el `OnBindViewHolder` de un `RecyclerView` donde si cumple la condicion puede cargar el `CardView`, pero si no la cumple le envio un `return;`
para que continue con el siguiente registro de la lista.

El problema es que me deja el `CardView` del registro que no cumple la condición en blanco.

Como puedo hacer que si no cumple la condicion cargue el siguiente registro de la lista string en lugar de que deje el CardView tal cual se diseño (vacío sin cargar nada)?

Comment: ¿Lo que tú quieres hacer es que el `CardView` no aparezca cuando no cumple la condición?

Comment: Hola, y cual es el código o deseas una opinión? , revisa por favor [ask], saludos.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Si asi es, de momento utilizo el return para que salga del OnBindViewHolder que es la carga del CardView por lo que aparece el CardView vacio. Yo necesito que no aparezca (que el OnBindViewHolder siga con el siguiente registro).

Comment: @Elenasys Pues puse el codigo que estoy utilizando que es "return;" es una pregunta simple por eso es corta y sin un gran codigo que mostrar pero el que trabaja con RecyclerViews entendera sin problemas. Revise que fuera bastante explicativo el post.

Comment: Hola **te sugerimos revisar acerca de Cuentas Títere https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196**

Comment: Si no necesitas mostrar ese item en el recycler, mi consejo es que no le pases ese item en la lista, pasa sólo aquello que necesites mostrar.